# div scroll start Position

Tags: javascript, css

Hi 
Am using div over table to scroll overflow content used some js frame work to fix header and scroll only results rows but mine problem is scroll position starts from the table header so wanna scroll position start from tbody

Column1Column2
Results1Results2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna do using CSS then:

First try using css property `overflow:auto`

look at [this](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html).
Also [this](http://www.agavegroup.com/?p=31) and [this](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/7700.htm) can be helpful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd links in this answer are no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Which framework you are using?

If it is JSF [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611733/jsf-1-1-data-table-header-freezing-issue-header-is-moving-up-when-scroll-down-in/4612786#4612786) would help you.

Or else if any other then you have to just separate your header and body. And apply css accordingly as described by me in above post.